# How to implement user inbox/message s like on stackoverflow?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, laravel

I have been looking at various approaches to in browser user messages. For instance stackoverflow and airbnb. I looked at airbnb's approach with firebug and was shocked at how absurdly complex it is with so many nested divs, etc. Quite nightmarish. Some sort of react implementation.

In contrast, stackoverflow has a far more elegant approach. I would like to do something similar for my site. But I have some questions below.

I see the messages are part of the header navigation menu. The first div that seems to be related is

```
<div class="-dialog-container js-topbar-dialog-corral">
```

Then the other divs that appear seem to be for the other icons to right of the inbox icon, but they appear in strange order:

```
 <div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog dno"
      style="top: 57px; right: 15px; display: block;">
```

This is for communities menu.

```
<div class="topbar-dialog inbox-dialog dno"
     style="top: 57px; right: 129px; display: none;">
```

This is for inbox

```
<div class="topbar-dialog help-dialog js-help-dialog dno"
     style="top: 57px; right: 53px; display: none;">
```

This is help

```
<div class="topbar-dialog achievements-dialog dno"
     style="top: 57px; right: 91px; display: none;">
```

This is for achievements

**Why are these ordered in a way that doesn't correspond to the physical layout?**

Then next we see

```
<ol class="-list">

<li class="-item">
    <a href="#" class="-link js-inbox-button topbar-icon-on"
       title="Recent inbox messages">
```

and so on for other menu items. This is more sensible since the items correspond to the ordering of the actual layout (inbox, achievements, help, community).

**Why this approach? What is the point of the oddly ordered divs that precede this ordered list? Conceptually, what is going on here?**

**How would one modify this approach to add a little X next to messages for a user to delete the message and then for the other messages to move accordingly to fill up the space from the deleted message?**

**Lastly, given that I am using Laravel 5.3, is there any recommended approach in terms of jquery vs angular vs vue for implementing this?**

Keep in mind I am not a developer - I just know enough to be dangerous, but if I am shown how to accomplish a coding task I can figure it out and adapt to my situation.

Thanks!

Brian